# Disable <ALT> key on Unity 2D?

Tags: unity

I'm using Photoshop through Wine and the ALT key is currently mapped to the window picker. However, I need the functionality of the ALT key within Photoshop. In previous Ubuntu versions I could change it under Preferences > Windows. How can it be done in Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 2D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to launch gconf-editor and navigate to Apps>metacity>general, then change mouse_button_modifier to `<Super>`.